# Accesing Google OAuth in Google colaboratory

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-colaboratory, google-api-python-client

i'm trying to use Google OAuth in google colab to get access to gmail API, but can't run the flow, because flow.run_console() doesn't work cause it's OOB, and flow.run_local_server() also doesn't work.
Is there any other way to authenticate through OAuth in google colaboratory?